# chrome app window.open() cannot be closed later

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

I'm building a **chrome-app** and I need to open new tab and close it later on, here is a simplify version of my code:

```
open(url) {
    this.tab = window.open(url);
} 

close() {
    this.tab.close();
}
```

The **open method works**, but when I try to close, chrome thinks that the tab is already closed and just **do nothing** (there is no exception or something like that)

The exact same code **works perfectly on web** (tab is opened and then closed).

Tried to use `chrome.app.window.create` but it only allows local windows.

Is there any limitation that i'm not aware of?

Do I have any other solution besides building a chrome extension as well?

Comment: You cannot use open() in a Chrome app to get a reference to the opened page. I think that if you test the value of this.tab you will find it undefined.

Comment: yes that's what i suspected, just couldn't find any official info.

Comment: There is a specific replacement, but it doesnt give a reference to the created tab [chrome.browser.openTab](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/browser)

Answer (score 0):

To get the tab that is selected in the specified window, use  ['chrome.tabs.query()'](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) with the argument {'active': true}, then close it with  ['chrome.tabs.remove()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-remove).

```
chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function     (tabs) {
chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id, function() { });
});
```

Comment: as far as I know chrome.tabs is only accessible from chrome-extension and not from chrome app, adding "tabs" in the manifest permissions doesn't help..